# Universal Image Loader reuse images

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader

Using Universal Image Loader, is it possible to directly save images to disk and reuse those images between different runs of the application?

I know `imageLoader.displayImage(imageURI, itemHolder.image, options);` gets images from the cache the second time, but if you exit the app the cache is removed.

I want the display image method to save the image to a permanent location and use that location every time the app calls that method.

Is this possible using Universal Image Loader or do I need to find another way?

Comment: UIL can be configured to use a disk cache, see section "useful info" of this [link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Yes, I know, but cache by definition is not permanent. Instead of save in memory I used save on disk. I wanted to know if this is guaranteed to work between different runs of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
.discCache(new FileCountLimitedDiscCache(cacheDir, new Md5FileNameGenerator(), 1000))
```

option in ImageLoaderConfiguration

It work for me.

Comment: This actually seems promising. I'll give it a try when I get the chance. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I got Universal Image Loader working without any of this, but I was thinking of trying out Picasso library, for which this seems perfect.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the image to a hidden folder then re-use it any time.

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/.saved_images");    
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and this in your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

note the **`.`** I inserted before the folder name, which will make the folder hidden.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Of course you can save it to a folder, but is this the best way to do it? I'm working on an app for a restaurant and I'm trying to have an offline option as well, hence wanting to reuses the images.

Comment: I'm not sure if it the best or not, but this way is good and you can use it offline too. Good luck man.