# How to restart an activity correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, bitmap

I am trying to restart a activity but I want to save a bitmap and then reload the same bitmap once the application is restarted. Not sure if the following way is efficient to restart the activity.
This is how I am trying to restart the activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you explicitly trying to restart the activity?

Comment: ah, its because I am trying to exit a view and set the view back to the activity. hard to explain.

Comment: If you're opening an activity to get a view and pass it back to the original activity, shouldn't you be using startActivityForResult() to do this?

Comment: This is faisable as you do it, getintent -> finish -> startintent.... But i don't recommend it at all !! If you want to refresh data in an activity you should do it manually view per view so you can CONTROL what is happenning..

Answer (score 1):

You can restart an activity by using this.

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Comment: +1, but how can I make sure that _bitmapFiltered is saved first

Comment: check my answer here for saving bitmap http://stackoverflow.com/a/18812621/1932105

Answer (score 0):

there is method provided for recreating the activity
if you call recreate(); it will recreate the activity.
calling finish and startactivity is not clean method.
For saving data, there are multiple methods, like saving data in application class / static variables / storing data in previous activity / using counters.